# Unable to implement close function to the 'X' button to close the note. When I try to click on 'X' button, nothing happens to the webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, web-development-server

I have developed a webpage where notes can be added and deleted. I tried implementing the delete function to the webpage using JS but for some reason, the webpage is not performing any action upon clicking the 'X' button.

The html file where the button is defined:

```html
 <h1 style="color: #1b0e02;">Notes</h1>
 <div class="sub-container">
{% for note in user.notes %}
  <div class="note-card"> 
  <button type="button" class="close" on-click="deleteNote({{ note.id }})">&times;</button>
      {{ note.text }} 
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Upon clicking this button, the JS function deleteNode() is called:

```
function deleteNote(nodeId) {
fetch('/delete-node', 
     {method: 'POST', 
        body: JSON.stringify({nodeId}),
     }).then((_res) => { window.location.href = "/";});
    }
```

This JS function then sends a request to the python Flask module which is supposed to delete the notes from the database and redirect the webpage to the same home screen after deletion:

```js
@pages.route('delete-note',methods = ["POST"])
def delete_Note():
    note_req_file = json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
    print(note_req_file)
    noteId = note_req_file['noteId']
    note = Note.query.get(noteId)
    if note:
        if note.user_id == current_user.id:
            db.session.delete(note)
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({})
```

Here is the models of the database as they are declared:

```js
#These two objects follow one to many model - One user is mapped to many notes.

from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50),unique=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    notes = db.relationship("Note") #mapping one user to many notes
    
class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("user.id")) #mapping a note to a particular user
```

Please help in implementing the delete operation. I dont understand what I am missing.

Here is the screenshot of the webpage for your reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtmUs.png)

Comment: Check the route URL and function name:
In your JavaScript code, you're sending the request to '/delete-node', but in your Flask route, it is defined as 'delete-note'. Make sure the URL and function names match.

Comment: In your Flask route, you have specified methods=["POST"], but in your JavaScript code, you're not explicitly setting the request method. By default, the fetch request uses the GET method. Update your JavaScript code to include the method: 'POST'

Comment: Instead of on-click, the correct attribute name for the button click event is onclick. Update your HTML code to use 'onclick'

Comment: Is on-click correct or should it be onclick?

Comment: Thank you. The issue is fixed. 'onclick' attribute and 'delete-node' was the issue.

Comment: I have mentioned method: 'POST' in javascript function right? Is that not the right way to explicitly mention the post request?